# Unity super simple NetworkServer code error

Tags: c#, sockets, networking, unity-game-engine, network-programming

I'am a newbie of socket programming and Unity.
I got an infinite error after pushing demo play button with this simple Server code

```
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.Networking;

public class PaintServer : MonoBehaviour {

    public bool isAtStart = true;
    public int port;
    // Use this for initialization

    void Start () {

        Debug.Log("Start");
        SetupServer();
    }


    private void SetupServer()
    {

        if (NetworkServer.active)
        {
            Debug.Log("Server is already acitve");
            return;

        }
        NetworkServer.Listen(port);

        Debug.Log("Listen Complete");

        // system msgs
        NetworkServer.RegisterHandler(MsgType.Connect, OnServerConnect);
        NetworkServer.RegisterHandler(MsgType.Disconnect, OnServerDisconnect);
        NetworkServer.RegisterHandler(MsgType.Error, OnServerError);


        DontDestroyOnLoad(gameObject);
    }

    public void OnServerConnect(NetworkMessage netMsg)
    {
        Debug.Log("PaintServer received client");
    }
    public void OnServerDisconnect(NetworkMessage netMsg)
    {
        Debug.Log("PaintServerlost client");

    }
    public void OnServerError(NetworkMessage netMsg)
    {
        Debug.Log("ServerError from Master");
    }

    public void OnConnect(NetworkMessage netMsg)
    {
        Debug.Log("player connected!");
    }

}
```

I have no script except the code above. Whenever I run the program, there are infinite error message such that

> host id out of bound id {0} max id should be greater 0 and less than
>   {0} UnityEngine.Networking.NetworkIdentity:UNetStaticUpdate()

What is the problem and how can I fix it? please help me.

Comment: Did you set your port variable in the inspector?

Comment: @lcewine What do you me "set port in the inspector"? I also did it some possible port numbers such as 15000, 6321, 7894, however the result was same

Comment: You set 'port' as a public variable so I thought you may have forgotten to set the number in the inspector. Hard coding the variable while testing is not a bad idea. Once it is working you can make it public if you wanted to.

Comment: @Icewine did as you said. It also causes same problem. Sorry, I guess that it's not a problem about port number.

Comment: This code should work fine. Are you sure this is the only script in your project? What is your Unity version? Please make sure that no other script is running. This should work fine.

Comment: @Programmer I'm using Unity 5.6.0f3 Personal. I also got the same problem when I copied the script into a total new project and run it. Exactly speaking, the infinite errors come into when I clicked other side of Unity window. I got error after pushing play button and click desktop or something else.

Comment: Also, **Application has been suspended, all multiplayer features will re-init** message comes first and the infinite error follows.

Comment: Could you try and change `public class PaintServer : MonoBehaviour` to `public class PaintServer : NetworkManager`.

Comment: Disable your firewall. Make sure Firewall does not block your Unity Editor and your Unity app build. You can Google how to add applications to Firewall exception list

Comment: @Programmer Sorry, but I didn't understand what "Unity app build" is. I could disable "Unity Editor" which is an .exe file, however, can you help me how to disable Unity app build from my firewall?

Comment: If you're by any chance unfocusing your editor/app (by that I mean alt-tabbing your standalone app, or unfocusing the Unity editor while in play mode), [there is an ongoing issue with Unity dropping connections on paused apps](https://issuetracker.unity3d.com/issues/networking-console-is-flooding-with-host-id-out-of-bound-id-0-max-id-should-be-greater-0-and-less-than-0-when-connected). I'm currently fighting with the same issue.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, when Unity loses focus (clicking on another window or desktop), this error appears in the console. I solved it by setting my unity project to "**Run in Background**".

1. Edit -> Project Settings -> Player.
2. In Resolution and Presentation section look for "**Run In Background**", and tick it.

I hope this works for you or another one who fall in this issue.